# C++ random yields different numbers for same Mersenne Twister seed when using float precision

Tags: c++, random, std, random-seed, mersenne-twister

I need to run reproducible Monte Carlo runs. That means I use a known seed that I store with my results, and use that seed if I need to run the same problem instance using the same random numbers. This is common practice.

While investigating the effects of numeric precision, I ran into the following issue: For the same Mersenne Twister seed, `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(-1, 1)` returns different numbers than `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(-1, 1)` and `std::uniform_real_distribution<long double>(-1, 1)`, as the following example shows:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

template < typename T >
void numbers( int seed ) {
  std::mt19937                        gen( seed );
  std::uniform_real_distribution< T > dis( -1, 1 );
  auto p = std::numeric_limits< T >::max_digits10;
  std::cout << std::setprecision( p ) << std::scientific << std::setw( p + 7 )
            << dis( gen ) << "\n"
            << std::setw( p + 7 ) << dis( gen ) << "\n"
            << std::setw( p + 7 ) << dis( gen ) << "\n"
            << "**********\n";
}

int main() {
  int seed = 123;
  numbers< float >( seed );
  numbers< double >( seed );
  numbers< long double >( seed );
}
```

Result:

```
$ /usr/bin/clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ /usr/bin/clang++ bug.cpp -std=c++17
$ ./a.out 
 3.929383755e-01
 4.259105921e-01
-4.277213216e-01
**********
 4.25910643160561708e-01
-1.43058149942132062e-01
 3.81769702875451866e-01
**********
 4.259106431605616525145e-01
-1.430581499421320209545e-01
 3.817697028754518623166e-01
**********
```

As you can see, `double` and `long double` both start around at the same number (save precision differences) and continue yielding the same values. On the other hand, `float` starts off with a completely different number, and its second number is similar to the first number produced by `double` and `long double`.

Do you see the same behavior in your compiler? Is there a reason for this unexpected (to me) discrepancy?

### Approach

The responses make it clear that there's no reason to expect that values generated with different underlying precision will be the same.

The approach that I'll take to generate reproducible runs will be to always generate values at the highest precision possible, and cast them to lower precision on demand (e.g., `float x = y`, where `y` is `double` or `long double`, as the case may be).

Comment: Why do you expect them to generate the same numbers?

Comment: As long as the same seed leads to the same sequence of `float`s, I don't see a problem

Comment: @MaxLanghof because I'm using the same algorithm with the same seed.

Comment: If float and double have different precision then the same transformation applied to them can result in different outcomes due to rounding error.  As long as each type always gives you the same sequence for the same seed your implementation is conforming.

Comment: @HongOoi the problem is that I need to compare the same run with two precisions. Not just any valid run, but two runs using the same values (to within their precision).

Comment: But it's a different output type. Surely you would not expect that a uniform random over ints would produce the same values as for doubles (which would obviously be impossible unless the random doubles are all required to be integers...). Same deal with `float` vs `double`...

Comment: @MaxLanghof Sure, but it is unexpected to me that the difference between `float` and `double` is in more than the precision (same algorithm applied to floating point types).

Comment: @NathanOliver agreed, but I think it is more than that. For example: the second `float` number is essentially the same as the first `double` and `long double`. That tells me that the story is not *only* precision  in this case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's it. I failed to see the underlying reason which is precisely this one: the generator will yield as many bits as the distribution requires, and `float` will use half as many.

Comment: @Escualo Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each distribution will generate floating point numbers by grabbing a sufficient number of (pseudo)random bits from the underlying Mersenne Twister and then producing uniformly distributed floating point numbers from it.

There are only two ways that an implementation could fulfill your expectation of "same algorithm, therefore same results (minus precision)":

1. `std::uniform_real_distribution<long double>(-1, 1)` is only as random as `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(-1, 1)`. More to the point, the former has exactly as many possible outputs as the latter. If the latter can produce more different values than the former, then it needs to consume more bits of randomness from the underlying Mersenne Twister. If it cannot - well, what's the point of using it (and how would it still be "uniform")?
2. `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(-1, 1)` consumes (and mostly discards) exactly as many bits of randomness from the underlying Mersenne Twister as `std::uniform_real_distribution<long double>(-1, 1)`. That would be very wasteful and inefficient.

Since no sane implementation will do either of the above, `std::uniform_real_distribution<long double>(-1, 1)` will advance the underlying Mersenne Twister by more steps than `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(-1, 1)` for each generated number. That will of course change the progression of the random numbers. This also explains why the `long double` and `double` variant are relatively close together: They share most of their random bits initially (whereas float likely requires a lot fewer bits and thus diverges quicker).

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I guess I got it wrong (the other way around): the fact that `double` and `long double` are "the same" is a coincidence (due to the underlying higher precision of `double`). In general, I should *not* expect the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure that truncating uniformly generated `long double`s to `float`s would end up with uniformly generated `float`s, so it could be the case that 2 *can't* be conforming. 1 certainly isn't

Comment: @Caleth For variant 2 I meant that it throws away those bits, not that it uses them for extended precision + truncation. In other words, I mean that all distributions will advance their RNG state by the same amount for the sake of it (without any change in how many bits they actually use).

Answer (score 2):

Initializing a random number generator to a specific seed will specify the sequence of random bits it puts out. However, you aren't using those bits the same way in each case. A `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>` has a larger possibility space than `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>` (assuming `sizeof(double) > sizeof(float)` on your platform) so it will need to consume a larger quantity of random bits to generate a fully uniform distribution.

The first consequence is that the pseudo-random sequence of bits will have a different interpretation for different distribution types. The second consequence is each distribution moves a different number of bits down the pseudo-random sequence whenever is produces a value, meaning following numbers won't be at the same point in the pseudo-random bit sequence.

The solution to your problem is to always use the same type of distribution. If you want to compare the result of using lower precision values with using higher precision values, only generate values with the highest precision and truncate them down when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to excellent @MaxLanghof answer with more specifics:

For double code would do something like this - generate u64 integer, and use 53bits of it to make float, along the lines

```
double r = (u64 >> 11) * (1.0 / (uint64_t(1) << 53));
```

For long double, assuming Intel 80bits format, with 64bit mantissa, it will do about the same, get 64bits, return back long double.

```
long double r = u64 * (1.0 / (uint64_t(1) << 64)); // pseudocode
```

64bit of randomness are consumed in both cases, thus you see same values.

In case of a float, 32bits are used to make single float

```
float r = (u32 >> 8) * (1.0f / (uint32_t(1) << 24));
```

32bits of randomness are consumed, and another 32bits are used for next number, which together with endianness makes second float about the same as first double/long double.

Link: http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/